# Anandamayi Ma's prophecies?

Tags: guru, book-recommendation, siddhi

I have heard about ' Prophecies' about the World's Future offered by this Great Saint: however, I have not found them mentioned in any biography I could find. So true or hoax?

Comment: Please contact the Anandamayi Ma's website (https://www.anandamayi.org/).  You may get the required information

Comment: I have known a few of Sri Ma's close disciples and interacted with them on numerous occasions both privately and publicly. None of them ever mentioned anything about prophecies. I have read several of the books about Ma. Don't remember anything about prophecies. Had heard that She warned individuals on a few occasions as to be wary of certain individual actions in the future, but no 'world' prophecies.

Comment: Normally the saints will speak in a cryptic language, which is very difficult to decipher.  Their words can be interpreted in many ways.  Unless we know content of the prophecies made and unless we have spiritual bent of mind it is very difficult to comprehend the inner meaning